# API call stopped working suddenly after few months

Tags: android, json

I am using below code to "GET" data using alpha Vantage API. It was working before for about 2 months then it suddenly stopped working. I don't see any change in JSON data.

```
private int retrievefromnet(int count,String symbol)
        {
            String temp;
            String baseAddress = "http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY";
            String apiKey = "J63P";
            Uri Url = Uri.parse(baseAddress)
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("symbol", symbol)
                    .appendQueryParameter("interval", "1min")
                    .appendQueryParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                    .build();
            Log.d("createList","built URL: " +Url.toString());
            try {
                url = new URL(Url.toString());
                urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlconnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return 0;
                }
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                Log.d("createList","here");
                while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    DATA[count] += temp;
                }
                Log.d("unedited", DATA[count]);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("createList", "Error in url ", e);
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
```

For extraction of data from JSON.

```
try {
                    String List = "Time Series (1min)";

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(DATA[count]);
                jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(List);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - 34200000 );
                String currtime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                Log.d("currtime",currtime);
                jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(currtime);

                return jsonObject.getString("4. close");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("createList", "Error in json");
}
```

Log says This:

```
D/createList: built URL: http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=J63P
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 19(0x7777772e616c70),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
D/createList: here
E/createList: Error in json
```

Notice that the last log statement of try block in retreivefromnet is not showing nor is the log of the catch block.
DATA[] is a string array. It has been initialised before. Also, I checked that `reader` is null.

Help me find the issue.

EDit for Abhishek:

```
06-23 14:25:37.315 16817-16980/lcukerd.com.stocknotifier E/createList: Error in json
                                                                   org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                       at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
                                                                       at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
                                                                       at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                       at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                       at lcukerd.com.stocknotifier.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$createList.workonJson(MainActivity.java:596)
                                                                       at lcukerd.com.stocknotifier.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$createList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:404)
                                                                       at lcukerd.com.stocknotifier.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$createList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:376)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple. I just needed to replace HTTP with HTTPS. AlphaVantage might have changed something that's why it worked earlier but not now. Everything working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You are having JSON parsing issue. It is better to use GSON library to parse JSON.

EX:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YOUR_OBJECT response = gson.fromJson("your_json_string", YOUR_OBJECT.class);
```

You can use online tool to create java object from json.
EX: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

TRY THIS:

```
public int retrievefromnet(int count, String symbol) {
        String temp;
        String baseAddress = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY";
        String apiKey = "J63P";
        Uri Url = Uri.parse(baseAddress)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("symbol", symbol)
                .appendQueryParameter("interval", "1min")
                .appendQueryParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                .build();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            Log.d("createList", "here");
            String responseStr = "";
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseStr += temp;
            }
            Log.d("unedited", responseStr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("createList", "Error in url ", e);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that my Buffered Reader is having null value. So Json have nothing to work on.

Comment: Why don't you use existing third party library to call api (volley, retrofit etc..)?

Comment: I never felt the need of it. I am using basic API call that was possible without third party library. You think it can help?

Comment: I hit same api and data is coming in browser. So you need to check your inputstream reader code.

Comment: Yes. I don't know what to check its hardly a line of code.

Comment: I used Volley and it showed response error code. I googled it and found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

To find the issue use this code `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and share the logs along with the stack trace of the Exception object

Comment: Catch block of json says: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                           at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)

Comment: post the entire stack trace

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be that the format of the content of the json data has changed, have you check the json content, it have been modified. Could you compare a good json processed before with this new?

Sorry for my english

Comment: The problem is that my Buffered Reader is having a null value. So Json has nothing to work on. Also, there is no change in JSON data, I checked.